# login to facebook from my facebook application

Tags: facebook, codeigniter, authentication

am developing Facebook application using codeigniter framework, am using php-sdk function to connect to facebook libraries, and am using the following code to direct the user to login box if the user is not logged in to facebook

```
$params = array(
        'scope' => 'read_stream, friends_likes'  
        'cancel_url' => 'http://www.facebook.com/',
        'canvas' => 1,
        'fbconnect' => 0,
        'req_perms' => 'publish_stream, read_stream, read_friendlists,email',
        'redirect_uri' => 'http://apps.facebook.com/morganmarket',
        'next' => 'http://apps.facebook.com/morganmarket',
        'display' => 'popup'
    );
    $loginUrl = $this->facebook->getLoginUrl($params);
    echo '<script> window.top.location="' . $loginUrl . '"</script>';
```

the problem that when i try to use my application with out being logged in Facebook, it directs me to a page with the error

```
 The page you requested was not found.
You may have clicked an expired link or mistyped the address. Some web addresses are case sensitive.

Return home
Go back to the previous page
```

what is the problem giving that accordign to my code it should direct me to facebook login form then to my application.

Comment: Not sure but sounds like a bug on facebook's side...

Answer (score 0):

In my codeigniter app evrything is ok :)

stellar

```
$config['facebook_login_parameters'] = array(
                                        'scope' => 'user_likes, friends_likes, email',
                                        'display' => 'page',

                                        'cancel_url' => 'http://www.facebook.com/',
                                        'redirect_uri' => 'http://apps.facebook.com/amnestyapp/',
                                        'canvas' => 1,
                                        'req_perms' => 'publish_stream, read_stream, read_friendlists,email',
                                        'next' => 'http://apps.facebook.com/amnestyapp/',

                                        );
```

Chupacabra

```
class Chupacabra extends CI_Controller {

function index() {
    $this->load->model('fizzlebizzle');
    $result = $this->fizzlebizzle->get_user();


    if ($result['is_true']) {
        $this->session->set_userdata(array('facebook_uid' => $result['facebook_uid'], 'is_logged_in' => TRUE));
        redirect('secure', 'refresh');

    } else {
        //$data['page'] = 'home_view';
        //$this->load->view('template', $data);
        // tu logowanie


        $loginUrl = $this->facebook->getLoginURL($this->config->item('facebook_login_parameters'));
         echo '<script> window.top.location="' . $loginUrl . '"</script>';

    }
}

function logout() {
    $this->auth->logout();
}
```

}